# Cannot update to Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: upgrade, updates, do-release-upgrade, 21.04

I had Kubuntu 20.10.

But I have long uninstalled KDE and installed GNOME.

Now the update to 210.4 doesn't show up.

I have selected the option to notify me of updates for every new version (not just LTS) but "Updates" still shows no available updates.

Also `do-release-upgrade` returns:

> Checking for a new Ubuntu release
>
> No new release found.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct.

See the 21.04 [Release Notes](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/hirsute-hippo-release-notes/19221):

> Release Upgrades
>
> Upgrades from Ubuntu 20.10 to Ubuntu 21.04 are not enabled as it is possible for some systems to end up in an unbootable state if they use EFI version 1.10 - bug 1925010. Release upgrades will be enabled once an updated version of shim is available which is compatible with EFI version 1.10.

Comment: Is there a command that lets you check EFI version?