# ubuntu update faild after extracting 'hirsute.tar.gz'

Tags: upgrade, update-manager, 20.10, 21.04

Currently, I have Ubuntu 20.10. I am trying to update my OS to 21.04 using "sudo update-manager -d".
but after entering the command, update-manager crashes without any errors, my screen only shows the following UIs

[screen 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTWod.png)
[screen 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lhY9Y.png)
[screen 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBQqn.png)

After 3rd screen updater automatically closes

Comment: (1) Make sure your system is fully updated before starting and (2) check for and eventually disabled 3rd party repositories

Comment: before running "sudo update-manager -d" I have update the system using "sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade". how can I check eventually disabled 3rd party repositories ?

Comment: Try again with `sudo apt full-upgrade` instead and **there's a typo in my previous comment**: It should read "check for and eventually **disable** 3rd party repositories. You can open Software&Updates > Other software for that. Typically those don't prevent a release upgrade - the script just disables them - but on occasions software installed from and the repos themselves are what prevents a successful release upgrade.

Comment: I ran "sudo apt full-upgrade" and it shows no updates available, (0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.),  My "Other Software" tab shows some application on there, but none of them are selected. Do I have to select any thing from there?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot update to Ubuntu 21.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1334419/cannot-update-to-ubuntu-21-04)

Comment: *Do I have to select any thing from there?* No, you unselect if selected. That said, it's quite weird to have "something" there (other then Partners) and have nothing selected.

Comment: @user535733 it is true that 21.04 is not available for 20.10 as default, But as I know it available as a force update, that is why I am using "sudo update-manager -d" command

Comment: @ChanganAuto is there any other way for me to update my os to 21.04 ?

Comment: Whenever the online upgrade fails, a fresh install is the best and fastest solution.

Comment: @ChanganAuto after some research i found that, my system has un removed PPAs, I was able to list them by following command,    ''find /etc/apt/sources.list.d -type f -name "*.list" -print0 |     while read -d $'\0' file; do awk -F/ '/deb / && /ppa\.launchpad\.net/ {print "sudo ppa-purge ppa:"$4"/"$5}' "$file"; done''   , but when I tried to remove them using ''sudo ppa-purge ppa:<app-name>''  I got a error of ''Warning:  Could not find package list for PPA: <app-name>'' , How can I remove them?

Comment: Maybe you can simply comment it out (#) or remove it if you want by editing /etc/apt/sources.list.d