# 20.10 do-release-upgrade not finding 21.04

Tags: mate, do-release-upgrade

It looks like 21.04 is not available to me through upgrade from 20.10. This is happening on two machines and on another I had to use the `-d` switch.

I have followed all the steps suggested by the numerous posts on how to run `do-release-upgrade`

`do-release-upgrade` is returning "No new release found".

As instructed :

In `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` I have set `Prompt=normal`

Not so often suggested but apparently often works: I've tried two Canada repos and US-duke -- same.

After each repo switch I apt update, apt-upgrade,apt dist-upgrade reboot

What am I missing?

Comment: There's a problem with the upgrade and newer systems (UEFI) which has halted the roll out of upgrades. It will be resumed later so just hang on in there. See [this reference](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2021/04/why-you-cant-upgrade-to-ubuntu-21-04-for-now)

Comment: I've added that as an answer with more info as to it's source.

Comment: There has been a problem with the build queue for awhile now (thus its backlogged).  If you watch the release ML you'll have noticed them talking about it, and the frequent mentions of the size of the queue on IRC (which is reducing slowly...). Even if a fix was committed & waiting to build.. it'll get stuck in the build queue anyway, so there is no hurry on fixing it currently... (I've been waiting to post news on 16.04, but not all upgraded packages for that release are yet built for all architectures.. so 16.04 news waits... ETA was 29-April; 20.10->21.04 isn't critical yet...)

Comment: What are you missing??   You didn't read the official release notes for 21.04 & the updating from 20.10 details mentioned there...  (My summary [UWN quote] of Joey Sneddon writing, in the accepted answer below, was written by Joey based on official documents themselves... so it's best to read the official documentation in my opinion; get direct information by reading release notes)

Comment: @guiverc As you say, for sure. However with the attention given the  rollout announcement, I would expect a similar level of notification for the postponement of it. I'm thinking of a news outlet headlining criminal charges then burying the acquittal. Actually the reverse of that but anyway yes thanks for the tip.

Comment: Given the official release notes mentioned the delay I don't see what else we can do. I'm involved in QA-testing, and we report all bugs we discover in testing, they are rolled up and included (documented in the release notes if considered an issue) & become official records. We cannot help what 3rd parties write there-after, but the official releases mentioned (at release time) the issue so nothing was hidden to anyone who looked & read the notes.  This release was no different to any prior cycle I've been involved with.

Comment: @guiverc Of course. The issue is that I'm following the lead of The Press rather than the official information releases. Lesson learned.And thank you for your work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a problem with the upgrade and newer systems (UEFI) which has halted the roll out of upgrades temporarily.

It will be resumed so just hang on in there for now until it's fixed.

This doesn't seem to affect vanilla installations from scratch though.

This from Ubuntu Weekly newsletter issue 681 [link here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuWeeklyNewsletter/Issue681)

> Joey Sneddon writes about the bug that impacts upgrades from Ubuntu
> 20.10 to Ubuntu 21.04 that has resulted in the decision of Ubuntu developers to not enable upgrades yet. Joey quotes Canonical's Brian
> Murray's advice which is to wait until the issue has been fixed and
> the upgrade path is turned on officially.

[reference](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2021/04/why-you-cant-upgrade-to-ubuntu-21-04-for-now)

Comment: It's also documented in the [21.04 Release Notes](https://askubuntu.com/a/1334421/19626)