# Failed to update ubuntu 20.10 to 21.04

Tags: updates, update-manager, 20.10, 21.04

I am trying to update my ubuntu 20.10 system to 21.04. When I ran `sudo do-release-upgrade -d` it Aborts with the following logs. I have also tried with Software Updater UI as well, it also fails.

```
Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]                                                                                                                                                                              
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,269 kB]                                                                                                                                                                                     
Fetched 1,270 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                                                                                    
authenticate 'hirsute.tar.gz' against 'hirsute.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'hirsute.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Hit http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy InRelease                                                                                                                                                          
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-security InRelease                                                                                                                                                   
Hit http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-updates InRelease                                                                                                                                                  
Hit http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu groovy-backports InRelease                                                                                                                                                
Fetched 0 B in 0s (0 B/s)                                                                                                                                                                                         
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done``
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot update to Ubuntu 21.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1334419/cannot-update-to-ubuntu-21-04)

Comment: No, I am using force update on this,  so ubuntu 21.04 is available for me, the issue is it is not working

Comment: It is *working*. Your output suggests that apt is not broken. It downloads, calculates, determines that the release-upgrade cannot succeed with your current settings, and aborts to avoid damaging your system. Review your apt logs for clues to the cause of the abort.

Comment: term.log is not updating, when running the command it whos as ``14 21:35 term.log
``